# Do computer terminology questions belong here or on EL&U?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

[This comment](https://superuser.com/questions/490675/what-is-the-difference-between-load-and-fetch#comment583763_490679) suggests that [a question I asked](https://superuser.com/questions/490675/what-is-the-difference-between-load-and-fetch) about computer terminology should be on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) instead.  This question isn't off topic for Super User because it is a computer-related question.  Should such questions be on EL&U instead, or should they remain on Super User?

Comment: I asked in the [english] chat what they think about it: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6581061#6581061

Comment: I'm not sure that EL&U wants these questions. Certainly [we've rejected programmers looking for method names](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1088). That said, the question of whether they're on topic for EL&U and the question of whether they're on topic for SU are two separate questions which can be arrived at independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know the difference between the two operations that are described by the two terms, it's perfect for Super User.

If you want to know the difference between to English terms that may be used to describe a variety of operations/objects/etc., then that question is most likely better suited for English Language & Usage.

If you're **sure** that the terms describe aspects related to personal computing (or any other topic this site is about), then provide examples of how the term was used.

Comment: The question has been further clarified to specify that it relates to computers.

Comment: @DragonLord: In that specific case, I would agree with Ignacio, that the terms are still too generic, even in the given context.

Comment: I've edited the question again to bring the question back on topic.

Comment: @DragonLord: Well, I never really wanted to give the impression that it's off-topic. You just might get a more specific definition on [english.se].

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Do you think something like [this](http://superuser.com/questions/612834/what-do-you-call-bits-bytes-kb-mb-gb) would be better suited to EL&U? I don't see SU as a great place for it personally. Not sure of [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/612767/what-does-the-term-overinstallation-mean) though.